# install libmariadbclient-dev on debian jessie

Tags: debian, mariadb

I have to install libmariadbclient-dev on my Debian8, but can't:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package libmariadbclient-dev
```

What should I do, please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install it from MariaDB repository.

Use the [repository configuration tool](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories) to choose the right architecture, version and mirror.

Follow instructions that appear on the page.

Example (don't use it as is, make sure you've chosen the right version and architecture, and a suitable mirror)!

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 0xcbcb082a1bb943db
sudo add-apt-repository 'deb [arch=amd64,i386,ppc64el] http://mirror.netinch.com/pub/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian jessie main'
sudo apt-get update
```

> You can also create a custom MariaDB sources.list file. To do so, copy
>   and paste the following into a file under /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ (we
>   suggest naming the file MariaDB.list or something similar), or add it
>   to the bottom of your /etc/apt/sources.list file.

```
# MariaDB 10.0 repository list - created 2016-12-30 14:56 UTC
# http://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/
deb [arch=amd64,i386] http://mirror.netinch.com/pub/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian jessie main
deb-src http://mirror.netinch.com/pub/mariadb/repo/10.0/debian jessie main
```

After you have configured the repo, run `apt-get update` and then install the package the same way as you tried before:

```
sudo apt-get install libmariadbclient-dev
```

Comment: Thank you, it helps